# Covert pandas into list

Tags: pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns:

```
  Stock1  Stock2    
0   SPXS  SPXU   
1    IAU   GLD   
2      C  JETS
```

I want to turn the columns into a list I can pass through other code like this:

```
pairs = (['SPXS', 'SPXU'], ['IAU', 'GLD'], ['C', 'JETS'])
```

So that I can call them in a for loop

```
for pair in pairs:        
    stock1 = pair[-2]
    stock2 = pair[-1]
```

Looking for the help as to the best way to execute this.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: Use `df.to_numpy()` or `df.values.tolist()`.

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik , I adjusted the question slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip loop for

```
pairs = []
for i,k in zip(df.Stock1,df.Stock2):
       pairs.append([i,k])
```

Now you can run on your new list:

```
for pair in pairs:
    stock1 = pair[-2]
    stock2 = pair[-1]
    print(stock1,'|',stock2)
```

This prints the following:

```
SPXS | SPXU
IAU | GLD
C | JETS
```